# Using variables and lists from editor in the Haskell console

Tags: function, variables, haskell, functional-programming, global-variables

The program should check if the number 2 belongs to the set A. But the value of x (2) and the set A (1, 2, 4, 5) I want to define in the editor and not in the console. I have this code:

```
x = 2
let A = [1, 2, 4, 5];

checkIfElem :: Nat -> Bool
checkIfElem x A
          |x`elem` A =True
          |otherwise = False
```

It tells me incorrect indentation and I don't know why
I just want it to return a true or false, I don't want and don't have to ask for a number or a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As the user amalloy rightly mentions, in Haskell the names of the variables (whatever their type and data) and the lists must be defined in lowercase since uppercase letters are defined for types.

The contents of variables and lists can be declared inside a .hs file without problems (no error).

In the example I put above it would be:

```
x = 2
a = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Next, the definition of the function

```
checkIfElem :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
checkIfElem x (a:xs) 
         |x`elem` (a:xs)=True
         |otherwise=False
```

The function `checkIfElem` receives an integer, a list of integer and returns a boolean value

Now, to call the function using the variable and the list defined in the editor and for Haskell to execute the function with the respective values stored in them, you must write the name of the function and then the variables needed by that function, according to whatever you need such function.

Note: Variables, even if they are lists, are always placed "without further ado", that is, only variables without straight brackets and no other typographical ones.

In Haskell console type:

```
Prelude> checkIfElem x a
```

Then, Haskell will answer us `True` since the value stored in the variable `x` (which is 2) is in the list `a` (which is made up of the values 1, 2, 4, 5)

Comment: Note that it's not true that uppercase is for types. Rather, uppercase is for *constructors*, both type constructors and data constructors (`Int`, `Either`, `True`, for example). Lowercase is for variables, both type variables and value variables (the `a` in `[a] -> Int`, the `f` and `x` in `f x`, for example).

Answer (score 6):

- You can't use `let` at the top level. Just define variables with no preamble, as you did with `x`.
- `A` is an illegal variable name. Variables must start with a lowercase letter.
- The type of `checkIfElem` claims it has one argument, but its definition has two.